# How can i get the content between ?> and <?php

Tags: php, oop, xhtml

getThis is just a personal learning question. I want to retrieve all the content between my function $page->content_start(); and $page->content_end(); how is the best way to get it? I don't want to include it or echo it, is it possible?

Thank you very much, your advices is very appreciated

```
<?php 

include 'pages/indexpage.class.php';
include 'modules/monmodule.class.php';

$page = new IndexPage();
$mod = new MonModule($page);
$mod->create();

$page->content_start();
?>
<div class="asss_ass"></div>
<span></span>
<?php
$page->content_end();
print_r($page->get_content());
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean, you want to "retrieve" it?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: "personal learning question" you are not learning if you are asking us, just saying :-)

Comment: ^ exactly. do you want to get the content of class asss_ass or the one in the span?

Comment: i want to learn from you cause i'm blocked... retrieve i mean get all content

Comment: You are generating the content, why do you want to retrive it again ?

Comment: i want to get all the html content between $page->content_start(); and $page->content_end();

Comment: i want to get it to append it to my body with dom, it's a personnal experimentation

Comment: @MikeBoutin: It's really not clear what you're trying to do, and it sounds like it's a disconnect of terminology and of understanding what server-side code and client-side code do.  If you want to append to the content server-side, just write the appended code in the file or `echo` some values from PHP.  If you want to do it client-side, you're talking JavaScript not PHP, which is entirely different.

Comment: well if you want to get the content of the div or span. i believe jquery can provide you with a solution. i remembered getting the contents of a div to process it for printing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
?>
<div class="asss_ass"></div>
<span></span>
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: `ob_start();` needs to be *in* the PHP block :P

Comment: i tried it, but i want to have all the content and put it in my $page->get_content() to create to whole page with it

Comment: You can also use `ob_get_clean` :-)

Comment: @Rocket: I didn't know that, changed! @Mike: You can use `$content` however you want, everything is in that variable.

Comment: That's it ! Rocket you win ty and Jeroen ^^