# How to replace <!--etc--> With A Variable

Tags: php, replace

I have a variable `$email` that need to replace all `<!--email-->` in my script.

Can someone guide me the best way to do that, currently im doing:

```
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
str_replace("<!--email-->",$email,"<!--email-->")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$filename = 'script.php';
$script = str_replace("<!--email-->",$email,file_get_contents($filename));
```

It will change all  in your file and you just have to save it or echo it

Comment: <!--email--> will be in the same document as the replace code so script.php couldnt be used

Comment: Check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840848/how-can-i-get-the-content-between-and-php

The $content will be the content

Comment: content will be taken from `$number['content'];` how would i make it search that?

Comment: this works `$script = str_replace("<!--email-->",$email,$number['content']);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 4 liner which will essentially grab all your `<!--tag-->` and replace them with the appropriately named variable:

```
$string = "string or output from file_get_contents()";

preg_match_all("/<!--([A-z0-9_]+)-->/", $string, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match){
$string = preg_replace("/<!--([$match]+)-->/i", ${$match}, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: this is awesome! saved me from having to define everything manually in my template system.