# Replace Placeholder and Echo Content

Tags: php

I have the content variable `$number['content']` with the placeholder `<!--email-->`  in it which needs to be replaced with `$email` variable.

Below is whats being stored in the content variable.
`<iframe src="url.com&em=<!--email-->&se=51" style="width:900px;height:700px;"></iframe>`

I need  to be replaced with the variable `$email`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace <!--etc--> With A Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751462/how-to-replace-etc-with-a-variable)

Comment: the same answer on your other question will answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would replace should work.

```
<?php 

$content = '<iframe src="url.com&em=<!--email-->&se=51" style="width:900px;height:700px;"></iframe>';

$content = str_replace('<!-- email -->', $email, $content);
```

If it is possible I would suggest using [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf).

```
<?php

$content = '<iframe src="url.com&em=%s&se=51" style="width:900px;height:700px;"></iframe>';

$content = sprintf($content, $email);
```

Comment: thanks i did str_replace('<!--email-->', $email, $number['content']); and it worked